# Can I send a URL request in OpenWRT using Lua?

Tags: url, lua, openwrt

I want to initiate a php program on my web server from OpenWRT running on a Linksys router. How can I do this? I don't have room to install elinks.

Answer (score 2):

use busybox wget http://192.168.42.220/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Using [Luasocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/) you can fetch a webpage (and thus triggering your php page) with [socket.http.request(url)](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html#request).

That is, if you have luasocket on your OpenWRT.